# Volley Request Tracking

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using volley library  for uploading images using Restful API
I made multiple image uploading  request and add all these  into RequestQueue.
when the request is completed I want to perform local db operation based on Request but

now the Question is how  can I track the progress of each request

How can I know that which request is finished ?

How can I TAG the request ? 
Any Way ?

Code :

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest (Request.Method.POST, Constants.IMAGE_UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String> ( ) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {

                        Log.e (TAG, s.toString ( ));


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener ( ) {
                    @Override

                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                //Creating parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String> ( );

                //Adding parameters
                params.put ("file_contents", imageString);// image string
                params.put ("file_name", filenameString);//profile image in name

                return params;
            }
        };

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy (new DefaultRetryPolicy (DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        //Adding request to the queue
        if (requestQueue==null)
            requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue (this);
        requestQueue.add (stringRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Volley [according to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), is not good for long operations and this means that it's not suited for your need
2. you can extend the request type you're using and add a custom field and then write a `RequestFilter` that will find the next item according to the returned value of the response

> Volley is not suitable for large download or streaming operations,
>   since Volley holds all responses in memory during parsing. For large
>   download operations, consider using an alternative like
>   DownloadManager.

Comment: I  am not performing any long operations ,just performing multiple small operations , request filter ?

Comment: uploading images is considered long operations